# laravel 5.2 Session not persist after login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Laravel 5.2 Session not persist after login, I have not used any
middleware or default laravel auth for login. I used native php login
 code,it works fine on local environment but on live server it makes this problem.

Comment: How is anyone able to help you without your code?

Comment: Do you have the StartSession middleware in the Kernel?

Comment: Where are you trying to access the session? It won't work in the service providers.

Comment: i am setting session using Session::put('key','value'); in logincontroller and retrieve it using sesion::all() in homecontroller. what does service provider  means ,i am novice to laravel

Comment: If you have your login credentials maintained between requests, then Session is working. Share your code where you set and pull variables.

Comment: --------- in logincontroller--------------

if(count($admin) > 0)
  {
   $admin['0']['type']='admin';

   Session::put('user',$admin['0']);
   Session::save();
   
   return Redirect::to('/');

  }

--------- in homecontroller--------------
return Session::all(); //returns empty page

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the permission of the folder **storage**, found in your laravel project directory, to 755